# Pandas, R, and interoperable data frame formats

Tags: r, pandas

I want to have a single format which is compatible both with R and Python's Pandas (and preferably, other things like Stata and SAS), for which I will not ever need to impute whether things are numbers or dates.

Does such a thing exist? Or has every package got their own system (Pickle, RDS, Stata `.dta`, `.sasb7dat`) for the purpose of lock-in?

Comment: https://github.com/wesm/feather

Answer (score 1):

Is your data in a data frame?  If so, [feather](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/) is what you're looking for.